# How to have button side by side horizontally?

Tags: html, css, button

This must be a really basic question for some people. I've been trying to figure out how to get my buttons to be side by side to each other, instead of one being on top of each other.
Here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <center><li><a class="button-small dinner rounded3" href="dinner.html">Dinner</a></li></center>
    <center><li><a class="button-small snacks rounded3" href="snacks.html">Snacks</a></li></center>
```

I'm a beginner, but any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: Do they have to be in a list? If they didn't it would be much easier.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, the ***only*** valid child elements of `<ul>` and `<ol>` elements are `<li>` elements; and `<center>` is long-deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You have the option of using simple css:

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    display: inline; /* or 'inline-block' */
}
```

With the corrected HTML of:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="button-small dinner rounded3" href="dinner.html">Dinner</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-small snacks rounded3" href="snacks.html">Snacks</a></li>
</ul>
```